# Configurable product is not showing out of stock items

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

We're running Magento 1.9.2.4

There are several simple products making up a few configurable products which we are wanting customers to be able to order if they are in stock or out of stock.

We're running custom themes and plugins, i've reverted back to RWD to ensure there are no template mistakes and disabled all of the plugins.

All options have been set globally, i've double checked the both the simple and configurable products to ensure that they are set with product levels and are in stock where applicable.

Cache has been cleared and all data has been re-indexed.

I've attached a screen shot of the settings.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x96aqhh2h9b86ik/Screenshot%202017-02-14%2018.59.54.png?dl=0

I've read lots of threads and there appears to be a few people that have had this issue on different versions of Magento but none of the fixes appear to have worked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I found the issue, the availability.phtm file needed updating to pull in another status.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the availability.phtm file needed updating to pull in another status.

There was an article I found online which helped, its not 100% right for 1.9.2.4 but got me most of the way there.

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct() ?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
<?php $stockLevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); ?>

<?php if($_product->isSaleable()<strong> && $stockLevel > 0</strong>): ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
<?php elseif($_product->isSaleable() && $stockLevel <= 0): ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock">
        <?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Available for Backorder') ?></span><br />
        <?php echo $this->__('Please allow up to two weeks for delivery') ?>
    </p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

https://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/ssssssssssssss.html